# How to manually set the value (and trigger the select event) to jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I know there are a few questions about this, but I couldn't find anyone that sets the value and also triggers the select function.

My code is:

```
$("#ux-selfservice-account-edit-nationality").autocomplete({
    source: countryList,
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.label).attr("oid", ui.item.oid);

        var select = $(this).closest(".ux-selfservice-account-box-edit").find(".ux-selfservice-account-edit-dni-type");
        // Check if the user has selected a different country (against the site)
        if (ui.item.iataCode == options.countryCode) {
            $(select).find("option").show();
        }
        else {
            $(select).find("option:not([value='PAS']):not([value=''])").hide();
            if ($(select).val() != "PAS") $(select).val('');
        }
        return false;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        return false;
    },
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).attr("oid", "0");
    }
});
```

The countries list is something like this:

```
[
    {
        iataCode: "AR",
        label: "Argentina",
        value: "Argentina",
        oid: 28515
    },
    ....
]
```

As you can see I have a very small check in the select function, if the user selects a different country I hide or show some options from another select drop down.

Now my problem is that sometimes I want the country to be set by javascript, so that the user sees the country name in the field, the oid is set to the attr and also checks the country.

Now I am doing something like this..

```
$("#ux-selfservice-account-edit-nationality").val(getCountryName(profile.personalInfo.country)).attr("oid", profile.personalInfo.country);
```

But of course this is wrong and doesn't check the other validation. also I can't do the validation here because I don't have the countryCode (iataCode). I know I can find it in the list, but the point is to use the same function of the autocomplete..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you extract the logic in the select event handler to a separated function that you can call elsewhere from your Javascript code?

All you need in that function is the country input (which is `this` in your current code, and the selected country json, which is the `ui.item`);

So you could extract your current logic into a new function `countrySelected`:

```
var countrySelected = function (countryInput, countryJSON) {
    $(countryInput).val(countryJSON.label).attr("oid", countryJSON.oid);

    var select = $(countryInput).closest(".ux-selfservice-account-box-edit").find(".ux-selfservice-account-edit-dni-type");
    // Check if the user has selected a different country (against the site)
    if (countryJSON.iataCode == options.countryCode) {
        $(select).find("option").show();
    } else {
        $(select).find("option:not([value='PAS']):not([value=''])").hide();
        if ($(select).val() != "PAS") $(select).val('');
    }
}
```

Then update your autocomplete declaration so the select event handler uses this function:

```
$("#country").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: countries,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //just call the new function
        countrySelected(this, ui.item);
        return false;
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        return false;
    },
    search: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).attr("oid", "0");
    }
});
```

This way you can also manually call the `countrySelected` function:

```
var countries = [{
    iataCode: "AR",
    label: "Argentina",
    value: "Argentina",
    oid: 28515
},
...
];
countrySelected($("#country"), countries[0]);
```

I have created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04jdky0j/3/) where you can see it in action.

Comment: Yes,  that is what i thought as a possible solution and that is why i wrote the last lines, that I have to find the country in the list and then pass it to the function, but if I could instead trigger the autocomplete select function using the oid, I would avoid this duplicate stuff. I think that this may be the best solution anyway as it seems to be no way to trigger the select

Comment: But even if you could trigger the select, you would still need to find which country you want to select, right?

Comment: You could use [jquery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to find a country in the list of countries given its oid. I have updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04jdky0j/4/) showing that.

Comment: Thats great, I did not know about the jquery.grep ! I think this is the only and the best solution. Thanks!